# Colab keeps disconnecting very frequently

Tags: google-colaboratory

I keep trying to connect to the hosted runtime on Google Colab, but it disconnects me after a few seconds (up to 10 secs).

The JavaScript Console of Firefox (the latest version) shows this:

`Error: "SocketIO error: xhr poll error: 0 - TransportError"`

I experience similar disconnect with Kaggle. How can I fix that? Thanks.

Edit: This may not be the final answer, but turning off VPN seems to fix the issue with Colab. Turning VPN back on does not cause the issue, but Kaggle still does not work, it might now just be a Kaggle issue.

Edit 2: With VPN back on the issue comes up again.

Comment: Does the console show any networking errors or changes? Does this behavior reproduce in an incognito window? Or, does this reproduce on different networks? (Perhaps a middle-box is closing long-lived connections that Kaggle & Colab use to maintain backend communication.)

Comment: @BobSmith Thanks for your response. I first turned off the VPN and it seems to fix the issue with Colab. Turning VPN back on the issue does not appear.

Comment: I get the cited error in console for a [different problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57815855/oserror-input-output-error-google-colab) - I don't use VPN; looking forward to any solutions